# "Enervate" and "intimidate"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

What is the difference between the words *enervate* and *intimidate*? Both mean *to weaken or to make timid*.

Comment: Have you checked in a dictionary? Their meanings are different. [Enervate](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/enervate) means *make somebody feel weak and tired*, but [intimidate](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/intimidate) means *frighten someone so that they'll do what you want*.

Comment: I was ______ by that man's presence! Which word fits here? Enervated or intimidated?

Comment: *Intimidated* if you mean that his presence made you feel frightened. *Enervated* if you mean that he made you feel tired because (for example) he talked too much.

Answer (score 3):

Intimidate may have a sense of **threatening someone** to make them feel they must do what you want. It implies the presence or operation of a **fear-inspiring force**.

> Atomic energy may intimidate the human race into bringing order into its international affairs

Enervate is a bit different, having a sense of "making you feel tired and weak". E.g:

> The hot sun enervated her to the point of collapse.

Comment: I was ______ by that man's presence! Which word fits here? Enervated or intimidated? I guess it's intimidated, is it not?

Comment: @Aditya, The context is not enough for me to decide. if "the man's presence" is a "threat", yes, it is "intimidated"

Comment: @Aditya: You should avoid *enervate* entirely. It's relatively uncommon, can literally mean *surgically remove the nerves*, and is often misused as a synonym for *excited*. Best not bother with it at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think **enervate** implies physical weakening and **intimidate** implies mental weakening.

> The lack of water left Bob **enervated** due to dehydration.
>
> The steepness of the cliff **intimidated** Bob.

Answer (score 1):

The original Latin etymologies can help here.

- *Intimidate* comes from *in* 'in' + *timid* 'fear' + the causative *-ate.*
- *Enervate* comes from *e* 'from' + *nerv* 'muscle' + the causative *-ate.*

So, originally, and pretty much still in modern English, to *intimidate* someone is to **frighten** them (*'fear into them'*) so that the intimidatee does what the intimidator demands.

Whereas, to *enervate* someone is to somehow take away their physical strength (*'from their muscles'*), by drugs, illness, or excessive labor. But *enervate* is also likely (perhaps more likely than *intimidate*) to be intransitive, and possibly a passive participle, referring to the result rather than the cause.

- He's just getting over the flu, and he's feeling rather enervated right now.
- He's just finished talking to the police, and he's feeling rather intimidated right now.